# bootstrap-vue:b-table how to prevent selectable table from selection change on some condition

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I need an ability to prevent b-table from the row selection change (by mouse click or by keyboard) on some condition. I.e. I need to show a dialog `save or cancel your changes before change row selection` and prevent selection change.

The `row-selected` event is fired when the row is already selected.
The `row-clicked` event is fired before `row-selected`, but `event.stopPropagation()`, `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, `event.preventDefault()`, `return false`, do not cancel further row selection change, i.e. `row-selected` is fired anyway.

I can't remove `selectable` flag, because previous selection will be lost in this case.

Also I tried the `busy` flag, but in this case there is no events from the table at all, and I can not send alert to the user, which is trying to change selection.

For now I am thinking about some mask for my table, but probably there is a more simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `no-select-on-click` prop to b-table. Check docs: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#data-row-accessibility